# Finding minimum line without subqueries - SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that has 3 columns: date, id and stake.

What I'm trying to find it the stake for each id at the earliest date

```
SELECT min(date), stake, id
FROM table
GROUP BY stake, id
```

However, this groups by stake as well as id before returning me the minimum dates. Hence, it doesn't work.

I'm currently doing an order by/partition + selecting the row number

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT date, stake, id, row_number OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC) AS rown
  FROM table
  ) t
WHERE t.rown = 1
```

However, I'm not really a fan of wrapping the tables multiple times so was just wondering if anyone had a more efficient workaround to this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You already have the best solution so don't bother with other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason at all to try to avoid subqueries -- unless you are using one of the very few databases that tend to materialize them.

This is still a subquery, but in many databases has the best performance:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select min(t2.date) from table t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

It wants an index on `(id, date)`.

Some databases extend the SQL standard to support a "first" aggregation function.  Some have other functionality for doing this.  A standard way that doesn't use a subquery is:

```
select distinct id,
       first_value(stake) over (partition by id order by date) as stake,
       min(date) as date
from t;
```

Either your version or the previous version should have better performance.